# How to get python webscraping to update better

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to make a python stock price checker. It is working well but it updates extremely slowly. It constantly runs and gets the information from https://money.cnn.com.

```
import requests, time, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import simpleaudio as sa

original = 0


while True:
    pfe = requests.get('https://money.cnn.com/quote/quote.html?symb=pfe')
    soup = bs(pfe.content, 'lxml').body
    price_pfe = soup.find('td', {'class':'wsod_last'}).span.contents[0]
    if (price_pfe != original):
        print("Pfizer price: " + price_pfe)
        original = price_pfe
```

Any tips to make it update faster?

Comment: make a session instead of getting new requests all the time.

Comment: Hey Daniel, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you update your question by clearly defining why you consider the current solution not fast enough? Is it about the execution time or something else? Would be helpful to see what is the current speed measure, and what speed you intend to achieve. As the commenter above suggested, you would most likely benefit from using a [Session Object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) which would keep a persistent connection to the website between calls.

Answer (score 0):

Using only lxml and xpath instead of bs wins twice

```
import requests, time
from lxml import html

original = 0

while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    pfe = requests.get('https://money.cnn.com/quote/quote.html?symb=pfe')
    tree = html.fromstring(pfe.content)
    price_pfe = float(tree.xpath("//td[@class='wsod_last']/span")[0].text_content().strip())
    print(price_pfe)
    if (price_pfe != original):
        print("Pfizer price: " + str(price_pfe))
        original = price_pfe
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```